# select a view by clicking osx 10.6

Tags: macos, cocoa

i created a image view

```
for(int i=0; i<pcount; i++)
{
    int x = rand() % 350;
    int y = rand() % 350;
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect((x+10),(y+10), 200, 200);
    //NSImageView *imageView 
    imageView1 = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
    [imageView1 setTag:i];

    // imageView = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
   // [imageView1 rotateByAngle:rand() % 150];

    [imageView1 setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];
    [imageView1 canBecomeKeyView];
    NSImage *theImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)[patharray objectAtIndex:(i)]];
    [imageView1 setImage:theImage];
    [[imageView1 cell] setHighlighted:YES];
    [[layoutCustom view] addSubview:imageView1 positioned:NSWindowMovedEventType relativeTo:nil];}
```

now how can select each image view by mouse click ?    thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that you have your reasons for not using existing collection views. So from what I read in your code you have layoutCustom.view, which contains a bunch of NSImageViews. Here are two options:

1. In your layoutCustom object implement the mouseDown: (or mouseUp: or both). Take the event location convert it view coordinates and look for any subview for which CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, mouseDownPoint) return YES. You should select that view.
2. Subclass NSImageView and implement mouseDown: (or mouseUp: or both). On mouseDown: simply set a "selected" flag. Either the view can draw something itself when selected or the layoutCustom object can observe the property and draw the selection accordingly.

I would prefer option 1 because it simpler, requires fewer classes and fewer interactions between objects.

```
// Option 1 (in layoutCustom class)

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    CGPoint mouseDownPoint = [self convertPoint:theEvent.locationInWindow fromView:nil];
    for (NSView *view in self.subviews) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, mouseDownPoint)) {
            // Do something to remember the selection.
            // Draw the selection in drawRect:
            [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        }
    }
}




// Option 2 (in Custom subclass of NSImage)

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    self.selected = !self.selected;
}


// Option 2 (in layoutCustom class)
- (void) addSubview:(NSView*)view positioned:(NSWindowOrderingMode)place relativeTo:(NSView*)otherView {
    [super addSubview:view positioned:place relativeTo:otherView];
    [self startObservingSubview:view];
}

- (void) willRemoveSubview:(NSView*)view {
    [self stopObservingSubview:view];
}

- (void) startObservingSubview:(NSView*)view {
   // Register your KVO here
   // You MUST implement observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:
}

- (void) stopObservingSubview:(NSView*)view {
   // Remove your KVO here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a better idea: Instead of fighting with converting mouse clicks in a view to coordinates and then figuring out how to map it to the right subview or sub-image, why not have one big (or scrolling?) view and then add your images as giant "`NSButton`" objects (set to custom type), where the button images can be the images you want to add.

As for how to select each image?  You can either subclass "`NSButton`" and keep track of some custom data within it, or you can use a "`tag`" to figure out which button was pressed in your "`IBAction`" method and then decide what to do with it.

Another approach might be to embed your images into NSTableView cells...

Comment: thank you Michael Dautermann... i'm preparing that imageViews for dragging with in superView...